# system() in C++, How to understand when it end its execution

Tags: c++, synchronization, system

I'm making a simple C++ project, where I display `figlet` text depending on the user's input.

Here's the code:

```cpp
std::string line, text;
std::ifstream tmp_file;
std::cin >> line;
text = "figlet -f" + line + " > tmp.txt";
system(text.c_str());
do
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    tmp_file.open("tmp.txt");
    output("File can't be opened correctly!");
} while(!tmp_file.is_open());
while(std::getline(tmp_file, line))

    std::cout << line << std::endl;
```

My idea was to storing `figlet` text in a temporary file and then reading each line of the file to print the result on the console.
The problem is that `system()` is a non-blocking function, so I don't know when tmp.txt is ready to be read and I would like to know in a "more formal way" when the system has ended its execution (without using `thread_sleep` for example) and then reading the file.

Comment: I've just made a transcription error, I put input in line that I append its content in another string (so it would be: "std::text = figlet -f" + line + " > tmp.txt";"
and than I pass text.c_str() to system ).

Comment: You can edit your question to fix errors or add additional information.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not really skilled on this site.
I did it ;)

Comment: Your understanding what `system()` does appears to be wrong. `system()` does not return until the executed program finishes. The only exception to that would be if the executed program forks and runs in the background, which you did not mention.

Answer (score 1):

The `system(3)` function is a blocking function, so it returns after the command has been completed and it's return value is the executed command return value. For example, [the `glibc` implementation](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/posix/system.c.html#143) of `system(3)`:

```cpp
  status = __posix_spawn (&pid, SHELL_PATH, 0, &spawn_attr,
                          (char *const[]){ (char*) SHELL_NAME,
                                           (char*) "-c",
                                           (char *) line, NULL },
```

---

<sub>This is not related to your question and is my suggestion to your problem. If you don't like it you could edit it and remove it</sub>

The `system(3)` function is bad:

- It's not safe:

  - You couldn't check if the wanted process exists.
  - You couldn't check if you run the exact process you want to run.

    - It could be easily replaced by another process with the same name.
  - You couldn't track its output without an OS-dependent trick (Like the Bash Output Redirection).

Alternatives:

1. Use the process APIs, if your desired program has any API use them instead of using directly with its binary.

   - For example [figlet](https://github.com/cmatsuoka/figlet) is a tiny program written in the C language and you could embed it in your code.
2. Use a third-party cross-platform Process Manager to run and capture your process more safely:

   - [Boost.Process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/process.html).
   - [QCore.QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html)

For example using Boost.Process:

- You could easily check if your process existed:

```cpp
auto const my_proc = boost::process::search_path("my_proc");
if(my_proc.empty())
{
    throw std::runtime_error("We could find: my_proc in the PATH");
}
```

- You could redirect the process `stdout` and `stderr` to somewhere else:

```cpp
boost::process::child proc(my_proc, arg, 
                           boost::process::std_out > stdout,
                           boost::process::std_err > std::err);
```

- And wait for it:

```cpp
proc.wait();
std::cout << proc.exit_code() << std::endl;
```

Comment: *It's not part of the ISO C++ standard.* Well, it is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

Comment: @prapin, Actually, it's part of the C standard: https://eel.is/c++draft/cstdlib.syn#header:<cstdlib> which is included in the C++ Standard. I did not know, thank you.